# Newton method for maps between Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods, banach-spaces

I am trying to understand the following theorem, which can be found in Kolmogorov and Fomin's (p. 509 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)):

> Let map $F$ [$:X\to Y$ where $X,Y$ are Banach spaces] be strongly
>   differentiable in a sphere $B(x_0,r)$ having centre $x_0$ and radius
>   $r$ and let the derivative $F'(x)$ satisfy Lipschitz
>   condition$$\|F(x_1)-F(x_2)\|\le L\|x_1-x_2\|.$$Let $[F'(x_0)]^{-1}$
>   [in $\mathscr{L}(Y,X)$, I would say] exist
>   and$$M=\|[F'(x_0)]^{-1}\|,\quad k=\|[F'(x_0)]^{-1}F(x_0)\|,\quad
> > h=MkL.$$Then if $h<1/4$, in sphere $\|x-x_0\|\le kt_0$, where $t_0$ is
>   the smallest root of equation $ht^2-t+1=0$, equation $F(x)=0$ has the
>   unique solution $x^\ast$ and sequence $\{x_n\}$ defined by recursive
>   formula$$x_{n+1}=x_n-[F'(x_0)]^{-1}(F(x_n))$$converges to this
>   solution.

The proof uses the fact that the derivative of $\Phi:x\mapsto F(x)-F(x_0)-F'(x_0)(x-x_0)$, which I guess we can be sure to exist only if $x\in B(x_0,r)$, is $F'(x)-F'(x_0)$ and that, if $\|x-x_0\|\le kt_0$, $\|\Phi'(x)\|\le Lt_0 k$. I wonder: is not it required that $kt_0<r$? Without such an assumption, I do not see how we can establish the existence of $\Phi'(x)$ for $\|x-x_0\|\le kt_0$. Does anybody know this theorem and what are the required assumptions? I have noticed that Kolmogorov-Fomin's sometimes states theorems valid only under unstated assumptions, and I fear this is one of those cases...

P.S.: I notice that the question has been downvoted: I would be grateful to the downvoter if (s)he made his/her vote more useful and suggest how to improve the question.